# Preventing localStorage QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage, storage, limit

I need to save a large amount of data through web browser `localStorage` intercepting the instance when it fills. I searched a lot and the only way I could find is calling a boolean method which try to makes new entries. I'd prefer to avoid this method.

I would like to know if a `localStorage` JavaScript function to know if it's full exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such method exists. The only way to test the storage capacity, is by attempting to add to storage, and catching the exception. See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface) for available methods of localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

The way normally used to prevent such interception is to add a check for the `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR` like

```
try {
    localStorage.setItem('item', val);
} catch (e) {
    if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
        alert('Quota exceeded!');
    }
}
```